# II7 installation on Windows Server 2008 (Amazon EC2) - how much time

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, amazon-ec2, installation

How much time it takes to install II7 on Windows Server 2008 via Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No more than 10 minutes on a large instance.

Comment: It's already runing 30 minutes or more and I tried both small and micro instanced. What's wrong ? - stuck on "Initializing installation"

Comment: did you ever get this sorted? if not were you using a custom image or one provide by Amazon? did you change any of the network settings?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be present because of the memory limits of the small and micro instances.

Try changing the Virtual Memory Page File from the fixed 256 MB preset size to 'Automatically manage paging file size for all drives'.

This allowed the installation to go through for me.

Here is a link on how to do this for Windows Server 2008:

http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-server-2008/adjust-page-file--virtual-memory-